# What is the purpose of Key in EmbeddedEntity?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

AppEngine Datastore uses `EmbeddedEntity` for nested entities. But I do not understand the purpose of `Key` in the `EmbeddedEntity`? When it can be used?

For example:

```
    Entity book = new Entity("Book");
    book.setProperty("name", "Hollow Man");
    book.setProperty("year", 2000);

    EmbeddedEntity author = new EmbeddedEntity();
    author.setKey(KeyFactory.createKey("AUTHOR", 123));
    author.setProperty("name", "Den Simons");

    book.setProperty("author", author);

    datastore.put(book);
```

Later I can fetch the `book` and to get the `author` from it. The `author` will have the key set, meaning the key is persisted. But is it possible to query with this key? The `EmbeddedEntity` javadoc says:

> It is not queryable when stored in the datastore.

So what would be the purpose of `Key` in `EmbeddedEntity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Embedded_entities shows how you can optionally set, as your embedded entity's key, the key to **another** entity of the same type that's **not** embedded, so that later you can "recover the original entity from the embedded entity".  Not a frequent need, I guess, but handy when you do need it, perhaps!

The relevant code snippet from there is:

```
// Entity contactInfo = /*...*/;
EmbeddedEntity embeddedContactInfo = new EmbeddedEntity();
Key infoKey;

infoKey = contactInfo.getKey();
embeddedContactInfo.setKey(infoKey);
```